# Plot ly Candlestick charts for stocks not from USA

Tags: r, plotly, quantmod

i've been trying R because it seems easy enough to create charts and do quick math analysis but i've run into a problem, the thing is i want to use plotly to graph my data but i cant make it work with symbols from stocks outside of US, here is the problem, im trying the first example from this page https://plot.ly/r/candlestick-charts/ and when i try to add the symbol BMV:BIMBOA instead of AAPL it will send me an error because of the ":"

Here is what i've tried

```
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)

Symbolname <- "BMV:BIMBOA"

getSymbols(Symbolname, src = "google")
df <- data.frame(Date=index(Symbolname),coredata(Symbolname))
df <- tail(df, 30)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~Symbolname.Open, close = ~Symbolname.Close,
          high = ~Symbolname.High, low = ~Symbolname.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")

# Create a shareable link to your chart
# Set up API credentials: https://plot.ly/r/getting-started
chart_link = api_create(p, filename="finance/candlestick-basic")
chart_link
```

and its not working,i get the error symbolname.open not found, as a side note if i use BMV:BIMBOA instead of the symbolname var i get the error "BMV" is not found.
i have tried using only BIMBOA but since the row in the xts object is called "BMV:BIMBOA.Open" its not working.

*Is there a workaround for this or any other way to read this data and work with plotly to graph this?*

Also tried this:

```
BMVBIMBOA <- `BMV:BIMBOA`

getSymbols("BMV:BIMBOA", src = "google")
df <- data.frame(Date=index(BMVBIMBOA),coredata(BMVBIMBOA))
df <- tail(df, 30)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~BMVBIMBOA.Open, close = ~BMVBIMBOA.Close,
          high = ~BMVBIMBOA.High, low = ~BMVBIMBOA.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
```

## The error is on the following 2 lines

```
          open = ~BMVBIMBOA.Open, close = ~BMVBIMBOA.Close,
          high = ~BMVBIMBOA.High, low = ~BMVBIMBOA.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
```

Comment: `\`BMV:BIMBOA\`` (it is present in your global env). (This question is not about `plotly`, it is about `quantmod`'s frustrating insistence on side-effect. You can always do `BMVBIMBOA <- \`BMV:BIMBOA\``, update `Symbolname`, and try again.)

Comment: tried it already the problem is the escape sign : like mentioned in the question

Comment: Are you literally including the backticks on the command-line? It works for me.

Comment: sorry can you give me an example of this? i tried this and its not working i get the error BMVBIMBOA.Open is not found
BMVBIMBOA <- `BMV:BIMBOA`


getSymbols("BMV:BIMBOA", src = "google")
df <- data.frame(Date=index(BMVBIMBOA),coredata(BMVBIMBOA))
df <- tail(df, 30)

p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~BMVBIMBOA.Open, close = ~BMVBIMBOA.Close,
          high = ~BMVBIMBOA.High, low = ~BMVBIMBOA.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems here:

1. The default mode of `getSymbols` is through [side-effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)), often (generally?) frowned upon. This is complicated by the fact that R does not generally like colons in variable names (though it can work just fine).
2. Your use of `index` and `coredata` (both within the `zoo` package, I'm assuming) is incorrect. Those two functions want an *object*, but you are providing a length-1 `character` vector (`"BMV:BIMBOA"`).
3. (I think) The column names in the resulting data are specific to the symbol, so `Symbolname.Open` is not found; replace them with the actual names.

Let's bypass the side-effect thing and hopefully get closer to what you want.

```
library(zoo)
library(plotly)
library(quantmod)
Symbolname <- "BMV:BIMBOA"
mydata <- getSymbols(Symbolname, src = "google", auto.assign = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(Date=index(mydata),coredata(mydata))
df <- tail(df, 30)
p <- df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
          open = ~BMV.BIMBOA.Open, close = ~BMV.BIMBOA.Close,
          high = ~BMV.BIMBOA.High, low = ~BMV.BIMBOA.Low) %>%
  layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
```

[image: BMV:BIMBOA plot]